# Creating new columns at 15 minute time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df which looks like the below.

```
Date    Hour    Minute  Val
2017-03-01  0   0       126
2017-03-01  0   15      119
2017-03-01  0   30      110
2017-03-01  0   45      56
2017-03-01  1   0       70
2017-03-01  1   15      59
2017-03-01  1   30      50
2017-03-01  1   45      41
2017-03-01  2   0       56
2017-03-01  2   15      63
2017-03-01  2   30      53
2017-03-01  2   45      66
2017-03-01  3   0       64
2017-03-01  3   15      78
2017-03-01  3   30      81
2017-03-01  3   45      79
```

I have to populate the dataframe with new columns at every 15 minute interval with the values of the "Val" column. My desired output should look like the below

```
Date      Hour Minute Val   T-30 T-15   T   T15  T30  T45
2017-03-01  0   0     126    Na   Na   126  119  110   56
2017-03-01  0   15    119    Na   126  119  110   56   70
2017-03-01  0   30    110    126  119  110  56    70   59
2017-03-01  0   45    56     119  110  56   70    59   50
2017-03-01  1   0     70     110  56   70   59    50   41
2017-03-01  1   15    59     56   70   59   50    41   56
2017-03-01  1   30    50     70   59   50   41    56   63
2017-03-01  1   45    41     59   50    41  56    63   53
2017-03-01  2   0     56     50   41   56   63    53   66
2017-03-01  2   15    63     41   56   63   53    66   64
2017-03-01  2   30    53     56   63   53   66    64   78
2017-03-01  2   45    66     63   53   66   64    78   81
2017-03-01  3   0     64     53   66   64   78    81   79
2017-03-01  3   15    78     66   64   78   81    79   Na
2017-03-01  3   30    81     64   78    81  79    Na   Na
2017-03-01  3   45    79     78    81   79  Na    Na   Na
```

I have tried pivoting my original dataframe to achieve the desired output but the output does not look like the desired output mentioned above.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Hour'], columns='Minute', values='Val').reset_index()
df.columns = ['Date', 'hour', 'T', 'T15', 'T30', 'T45']
```

The output of the above code looks like the below.

```
Date      hour  T   T15     T30   T45
2019-03-01  0   126 119     110   56
2019-03-01  1   70  59      50    41
2019-03-01  2   56  63      53    66
2019-03-01  3   64  78      81    79
```

I somehow cannot pivot the table retaining the minute and the values columns and also adding T-15 and T-30.

How can I get about doing this? I am new to python. Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `shift`

```
s=pd.concat([df.Val.shift(x) for x in l],axis=1,keys=['T'+str(-x*15)for x in l])

df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
```